# Including local dependencies in deployment to lambda

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, aws-lambda

I have a repo which consists of several "micro-services" which I upload to AWS's Lambda. In addition I have a few shared libraries that I'd like to package up when sending to AWS.

Therefore my directory structure looks like:

```
/micro-service-1
    /dist
        package.json
        index.js
/micro-service-2
    /dist
        package.json
        index.js
/shared-component-1
    /dist
        package.json
        component-name-1.js
/shared-component-2
    /dist
        package.json
        component-name-2.js
```

The basic deployment leverages the handy `node-lambda` npm module but when I reference a local shared component with a statement like:

```
var sharedService = require('../../shared-component-1/dist/index');
```

This works just fine with the `node-lambda run` command but `node-lambda deploy` drops this local dependency. Probably makes sense because I'm going below the "root" directory in my dependency so I thought maybe I'd leverage **gulp** to make this work but I'm pretty darn new to it so I may be doing something dumb. My strategy was to:

- Have `gulp deploy` depend on a *local-deps* task
- the *local-deps* task would:

  - `npm build --production` to a directory
  - then pipe this directory over to the micro-service under the `/local` directory
  - clean up the install in the shared
- I would then refer to all shared components like so:

  ```
  var sharedService = require('local/component-name-1');
  ```

Hopefully this makes what I'm trying to achieve. Does this strategy make sense? Is there a simpler way I should be considering? Does anyone have any examples of anything like this in "gulp speak"?

Comment: I have come across this problem too. It would be nice if node-lambda incorporated that. Otherwise, a gulp task seems to be the thing to do, but it feels very 'whacky' and convoluted. Will comment back here when I've decided what I'm going to do! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an answer to this! :D

**TL;DR** - Use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to link create a symbolic link between your common component and the dependent component.

So, I have a a project with only two modules:

```
- main-module
- referenced-module
```

Each of these is a node module. If I `cd` into `referenced-module` and run `npm link`, then `cd` into `main-module` and `npm link referenced-module`, npm will 'install' my `referenced-module` into my `main-module` and store it in my `node_modules` folder. NOTE: When running the second `npm link`, the name of the project is the one you find in your `package.json`, not the name of the directory (see `npm link` documentation, previously linked).

Now, in my `main-module` all I need to do is `var test = require('referenced-module')` and I can use that to my hearts content. Be sure to `module.exports` your code from your `referenced-module`!

Now, when you zip up `main-module` to deploy it to AWS Lambda, the links are resolved and the *real* modules are put in their place! I've tested this and it works, though not with `node-lambda` yet, though I don't see why this should be a problem (unless it does something different with the package restores).

What's nice about this approach as well is that any changes I make to my `referenced-module` are automatically picked up by my `main-module` during development, so I don't have to run any gulp tasks or anything to sync them.

I find this is quite a nice, clean solution and I was able to get it working within a few minutes. If anything I've described above doesn't make any sense (as I've only just discovered this solution myself!), please leave a comment and I'll try and clarify for you.

**UPDATE FEB 2016**

Depending on your requirements and how large your application is, there may be an interesting alternative that solves this problem even more elegantly than using symlinking. Take a look at [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless). It's quite a neat way of structuring serverless applications and includes useful features like being able to assign API Gateway endpoints that trigger the Lambda function you are writing. It even allows you to script CloudFormation configurations, so if you have other resources to deploy then you could do so here. Need a 'beta' or 'prod' stage? This can do it for you too. I've been using it for just over a week and while there is a bit of setup to do and things aren't always as clear as you'd like, it is quite flexible and the support community is good!

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll give it a try tomorrow. The lack of syncing -- while making the two projects more coupled -- will be nice for most my current use cases.

Comment: When I got home from work I put it into my own project and it's working nicely. I work on PC and have Mac at home so it's cross platform. Also, you can use the 'install' command multiple times once you've made the initial link from the module you want to distribute. Just change to every module directory you want to install it in and run the command again. :) good luck!

Comment: really like this solution for when active development is happening in both microservices. When a dependency slows down in development you can simply `npm unlink` and then point the dependency to a repo.

Comment: Ah nice, haven't got that far myself. I'm glad this exists because having to create some gulp task to copy or duplicate content would have been horrible and a really spanner in my workflow.

Comment: Next time I do this though, i will avoid the nested structure altogether. Just adds unneeded complexity and your solution will work fine when each service is its own repo. Much cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

While using serverless we faced a similar issue, when having the need to share code between AWS Lambdas. Initially we used to duplication the code, across each microservice, but later as always it became difficult to manage.

Since the development done in Windows Environment, using symbolic links was not an option for us.

Then we came up with a solution to use a shared folder to keep the local dependencies and use a custom written gulp task to copy these dependencies across each of the microservice endpoints so that the dependency can be required similar to npm package.

One of the decisions we made is not to keep two places to define the dependencies for microservices, so we used the same package.json to define the local shared dependencies, where gulp task passes this file and copy the shared dependencies accordingly also installing the npm dependencies with a single command.

Later we made the code open source as npm modules [serverless-dependency-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dependency-install) and [gulp-dependency-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dependency-install).